# Java ArrayList of ArrayList Scanner UserInput

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to store user input into ArrayList of ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

For example, storing it as `[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,1,8]]`
Below is my code,

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a set of numbers:");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = line.split(" +");

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        a1.add(new Integer(numbers[i]));

    }
    a.add(a1);
```

But then when I types it in to terminal, it becomes `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,8]]`.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you input the numbers? I mean tell us where did you use `+`?

Comment: You created two `ArrayList` objects. What other output would you expect?

Comment: Please provide details about your input. you have coded only for one ArrayList.

Comment: basically i typed into the terminal by entering spacebar between numbers. eg `1 2 3 4 5 6 1 8` on one single line

Comment: How will you identify which is the first array list and which is second ? Put some separator.

Comment: So, In your program Why did you split on `+`  and created an array?

Comment: @AniketKulkarni I thought this was the easiest way to make the userinput into an ArrayList. I have no problem when it is just one single ArrayList.

Comment: @user2875021 : I have posted my answer please find below. Hope it will help you in solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From above comments I am bit clear what do you want to do.

You entered `1 2 3 4 5 6 1 8` on terminal. In your program you used split on `-` so I am providing some guidelines to solve your problem.

First, split your input on `-` to make the separation of arrays

```
String[] numbersArray = line.split("-"); 
//e.g. input 1 2 3 + 4 5 6 + 1 8
//here you will get numbersArray as [1 2 3,4 5 6,1 8]
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Now, to separate individual elements of inner array use for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<numbersArray.length; i++) {

    String[] numbers= numbersArray[i].split(" "); //split on " "
    //here you will get [1,2,3] for first iteration and 2nd [4,5,6], last [1,8]

    ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int j=0; j<numbers.length; j++) {
        a1.add(new Integer(numbers[j]));
        //here adding inner array list elements

    }
    //add to main array list 
    a.add(a1);
}
```

Comment: however, when i am trying using your method, entering to the terminal like `1 2 3 + 4 5 6 + 1 8` i got a Runtime Error with `NumberFormatException`. not quite sure why thou.

Comment: I have figured it out. Instead of using `("+")`, I have used `("-")` and works like a charm.

Comment: @user2875021 : Fine. It's GOOD to see you have solved the problem. SO is always there to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this type of i/p and below code .

```
i/p : 1 2 3-4 5-6 1 8

String[] list= line.split("-");

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {

        String[] number= line.split(" ");
        ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
            a1.add(new Integer(numbers[i]));

        }
        if(a1.length>0)
           a.add(a1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the wrong input you are trying to enter on console, because when I hard code the ideal input to your ArrayList it prints the result as you expected. Here is the sample code that I wrote:

```
private static void doPrint(){
    List<List<Integer>> sample=new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a1.add(12);
    a1.add(23);
    ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    a2.add(22);
    a2.add(28);
    sample.add(a1);
    sample.add(a2);

    System.out.println(sample);
}
```

and here is the output:

```
[[12, 23], [22, 28]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to use, will not work since you add all elements to inner list.

You can try some thing like following. You needs to create following arrays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] arr1={1,2,3}; // you need to create these arrays
    int[] arr2={4,5};
    int[] arr3={6,1,8};
    a.add(getList(arr1));
    a.add(getList(arr2));
    a.add(getList(arr3));
    System.out.println(a);
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> getList(int[] arr){
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int anArr : arr) {
        list.add(anArr);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding only one list to `a` that's why it seems like one element inside list `a`. If you want to have multiple elements inside list `a` then use like this.

```
for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        a1.add(new Integer(numbers[i]));
}
a.add(a1);
a.add(a1);
```

**Output:** As per input taken in your question

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,1,8], [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,8]]
```